# Refer existing attribute when Reflection.Emitting

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes, reflection.emit

So here I am trying to generate a new class on the fly from an existing class using `System.Reflection.Emit`. Basically I want to take all public properties and fields from this existing class and slap them onto my new dynamically created class. So far so good, but now some of the fields from the existing class are being decorated with attributes defined in `System.Xml.Serialization` assembly and I'd very much like to have on my new fields as well.

However I'm not certain on how I should proceed. I suppose I should call `SetCustomAttribute` on my `FieldBuilder` instance, however this method requires a `CustomAttributeBuilder` and I don't know how to instantiate it correctly to have it refer on the true attribute... Furthermore I'd also like to keep existing attribute arguments in my new class.

tl;dr just trying to copy attributes from an existing class to a new one created via `Reflection.Emit`.

Comment: What did you try? How did that fail? Was the documentation of `CustomAttributeBuilder` unclear?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the constructors of `CustomAttributeBuilder` to instantiate that class.

Use `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributesData` to retrieve the meta-data about existing custom attributes. In contrast to `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes` this API does not instantiate the attribute classes. Instead, it returns you the raw meta-data.